# Using an object as a variable for a constructor

Tags: java, object, constructor

I have a question about using an object as the variable in a constructor. It might be simple but I just really can't think of what to do and my java book isn't really helping.  Say i wanted to do this

```
Fraction f3 = new Fraction(1, 2);
Fraction f5 = new Fraction(f3);
```

my constructor for the first object is:

```
public Fraction(int n, int d)

{
    if (d == 0)
    {
        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 1;
        System.err.println("Error: Invalid Denominator (" + d + ")");
    }
    else if (d < 0)
    {
        int nn = Math.abs(n) * (-1);
        numerator = nn;
        denominator = Math.abs(d);
    }
    else
    {
    numerator = n;
    denominator = d;
    }

}
```

my constructor for the second object is this:

```
public Fraction(Fraction f) 

{

}
```

I can't think of how to define the constructor to get it to set a new object as the object given. If anyone could give me a hand or maybe some advice to put me on the path to figuring it out I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is it intentional that if for n=-1, d=-1, numerator is set to -1 and denominator to 1? Note that `Math.abs` does nothing but test for "argument<0?" and returns -argument if yes, argument if not. Since you already established `d<0` where you call `Math.abs(d)`, why not write `-d`?

Answer (score 6):

```
public Fraction(Fraction f){
  this(f.numerator, f.denominator);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use "constructor chaining" to ensure the changes made to one are reflected in the other.

```
// copy constructor
public Fraction(Fraction f) {
    this(f.numerator, f.denominator); // call the regular constructor with f's params
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public Fraction(Fraction f){
  this.n = f.n;
  this.d = f.d;
}
```

Comment: Of course, this assumes 'numerator' and 'denominator' are defined as public members of Fraction

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this - if the logic changes, you're going to find a bug soon enough.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy No, because you're inside the file. You have full access to members of the same class, even if they aren't members of `this` object.

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy. No because the constructor is inside Fraction so it sees members of all visibilities.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. I had instance variables set up for numerator and denominator already.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something such that

```
Fraction a = .... ;
Fraction b = new Fraction(a);
System.out.println(a==b);
```

prints `true`? That is not possible in Java; `new` always produces a fresh object that is separate from all previously existing objects.

(This is in contrast to, say, ECMAScript, where a constructor is allowed to return an existing object and discard the fresh object the runtime created and passed as the constructor's `this`).